# Azure WebRole won't start after 1.7 upgrade

Tags: iis, azure, azure-web-roles

I've recently tried to upgrade my WebRole from Azure SDK v1.6 to v1.7. This appears to have worked OK. I can build and run the role in my devfabric just fine.  When I try to deploy the upgraded project to the real cloud, the instances never start. They just sit in the "busy" state. Interestingly, they don't do the typical "recycle loop", they just sit at "busy" forever.

When I log into the instances with RDP, I see the following error in the event logs:

> The application '/' belonging to site '1' has an invalid AppPoolId 'DefaultAppPool' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.

Followed by:

> Site 1 was disabled because the root application defined for the site is invalid. See the previous event log message for information about the root application is invalid.

Looking in IIS manager confirms that there is no AppPool called "DefaultAppPool". There also are none of the typical AppPools with GUIDs for names that Azure creates. Unsurprisingly, none of my sites exist either.

So how do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you tell us what you're doing in your WebRole.cs and in your startup tasks?

Comment: I put up a build that does no work in WebRole.cs, and has no startup tasks registered. It does the same thing, except that I get a ton of repeating event log entries in addition to the two I mentioned before. The new ones are like: "The application '/' belonging to site '1273337584' has an invalid AppPoolId '61574c81-73e4-4626-903c-72c05bb3963c' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored."

Comment: @breischl - have you found the cause of this error?  One of my projects has started throwing the same error and I can't figure it out

Comment: @breischl - after a lot of searching and even a restore, I found that disabling SessionState in the web.config was the cause of my problem - not sure why...  Removing the sessionState element let me debug as normal

Comment: @markpirvine, I never did figure it out. We've had SessionState disabled since we started the project, so maybe that's our problem too. I'll try that and see if it helps.

Comment: @breischl, One quick note, have a check at the version in the deployed application in the management portal is "1.7"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to v1.7, but upon looking at the Windows Azure logs in the Azure VM I noticed the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred. Type: System.ArgumentException Process ID: 2340
Process Name: DiagnosticsAgent
Thread ID: 1
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role Backend_IN_0
Exception: Endpoint http://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/ is not a secure connection.
```

So I changed the Diagnostics connection string to use `https` instead of `http` and voilá, that solved my problem.

Hope that works for you, I've been pulling my hair off for two days.